# Storing values in array in while loop

Tags: c, arrays, do-while

So the program is supposed to calculate the temperature from an initial temp given by the user which is then changed based on wind, humidity, and condition. first get a starting temperature from the user, then display a menu of choices that consist of entering wind speed, entering humidity, entering the condition, displaying the current temperature, displaying the last 1000 temperatures after the initial temp has been modified and displaying the sum of all temperatures.

I have done most of it but I'm having problems with how to store and display the last 1000 temperatures. I'm supposed to use an array in this program but I'm not sure how to use it to get what I need. Help, please.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define CLS system("cls")
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// PROTOTYPING FUNCTIONS
void askTemp();
float convertC(float f);
void displayMenu();
char getChoice();
char getCondChoice();
float getHumid();
float getTemp();
float getWind();

main() {
    // INITIALIZE VARIABLES
    float temp;
    float wind = 5;
    float humid = 20;
    int trump = 0;
    char choice = 'A';
    int num;
    char cond = 'S';
    char condChoice;
    float celsius;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    float temp2 = 0;
    float wind2 = 0;
    float humid2 = 0;
    int x = 0;

    askTemp();
    temp = getTemp();

    do{
        displayMenu();
        choice = getChoice();

        switch (choice){
        case 'W': // Get Wind
            wind = getWind();
            break;
        case 'H': // Get the humidity
            humid = getHumid();
            break;
        case 'C': // Enter subswitch statement to get condition
            condChoice = getCondChoice();
            switch (condChoice){ // gets condition 
            case 'S':
                cond = 'S';
                break;
            case 'C':
                cond = 'C';
                break;
            case 'R':
                cond = 'R';
                break;
            }// END SWITCH
        case 'T': // display current temperature

            if (temp != temp2 || wind != wind2 || humid != humid2){ // apply degree changes based on humid, wind, and cond
                if (wind > 100)
                    temp = temp - (temp * .03);
                if (wind < 10)
                    temp = temp + (temp * .025);
                if (humid > 75)
                    temp = temp + (temp * .058933);
                if (humid < 20)
                    temp = temp - (temp * .0162);
                if (cond == 'S' && wind > 30)
                    temp = temp + (temp * .01);
                if (cond == 'S' && wind == 0)
                    temp = temp + (temp * .005);
                if (cond == 'R')
                    temp = temp - (temp * .02);
                if (cond == 'C' && humid > 75)
                    temp = temp + (temp * .01);
                if (cond == 'C' && humid < 75)
                    temp = temp + (temp * .005);
                if (wind > 30 && humid > 75 && cond == 'S')
                    temp = temp;
                wind2 = wind;     // assigned variables so program does not apply condition changes multiple times for same temp
                humid2 = humid;
                temp2 = temp;
            }// END IF
        celsius = convertC(temp2);
        printf("The Current temperature is %.1ff/%.1fc degrees Celsius\n", temp2, celsius);
        PAUSE;
        break;
    case 'P': // Display previous 1000 temperatures

        break;
    case 'A': // Display average of all temps entered
        break;
    }// END SWITCH

} while (choice != 'Q');



} // END MAIN

void askTemp(){
    printf("What is the current temperature: \n");
    return;
}// end askTemp

void displayMenu(){
    CLS;
    printf("W. Enter Wind Speed\n");
    printf("H. Enter Humidity\n");
    printf("C. conditions\n");
    printf("T. Current Temperature\n");
    printf("P. Previous Temps\n");
    printf("A. Average Temperature\n");
    printf("Q. Quit\n");
    return;
} // end currentTemp

char getChoice(){
    char result;
    scanf("%c", &result);
    result = toupper(result);
    return result;
}// end getChoice

char getCond(){
    char result;


}// end getCond

char getCondChoice(){
    char result;
    printf("S for sunny, C for cloudy, R for rainy\n");
    scanf(" %c", &result);
    result = toupper(result);
    do{
        if (result != 'S' && result != 'C' && result != 'R'){
            printf("Invalid input try again\n");
            scanf(" %c", &result);
            result = toupper(result);
        }
    } while (result != 'S' && result != 'C' && result != 'R');
    return result;
}// end getCond

float getHumid(){
    float result;
    scanf("%f", &result);
    return result;
}// end getHumid

float getTemp(){
    float result;
    scanf("%f", &result);
    do{

        if (result < -50 || result > 150){
            printf("Invalid temperature try again\n");
            scanf("%f", &result);
        }
    } while (result < -50 || result > 150);
    return result;
}// end getTemp

float getWind(){
    float result;
    scanf("%f", &result);
    return result;
}// end getWind

float convertC(float f){
    float t;
    t = (f - 32) / 1.8;
    return(t);
}// end convert
```

Comment: Note that in C, all the 'prototypes' except the one for `convertC()` are simply function declarations and not prototypes. They say the fiction exists, but nothing about the argument list (except that it isn't a variable list).  To make a prototype, you need to include `void` inside the parentheses: `void askTemp(void);` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare an array of 1000 `float` like this:

```
float saved_temperatures[1000];
```

You store a value in it by indexing into the array, and using it like a variable.

```
saved_temperatures[i] = temp;
++i;
```

`i` is an indexing variable, and you should make sure it starts at zero and is always less than 1000. The valid index range for `saved_temperatures` is 0..999.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    printf("index %d temperature %f\n", i, saved_temperatures[i]);
}
```